# ARM Chroot installing xfce fails, packages named different

Tags: apt, package-management, xfce, chroot

I am trying to install xfce within an ARM chroot, most packages download  fine however a handful error out, after looking at the packages in the repo I have found that what apt-get is trying to get seems to be different to what the package is named.

For example, apt-get fails trying to get

```
http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/u/upower/upower_0.9.22-1_armhf.deb
```

when I look on the server this file is not there but  there is:

```
http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/u/upower/upower_0.9.22-1ubuntu1_armhf.deb
```

How can I fix it so apt trys to get the right package, there are about 15 packages that seems to be looking for the wrong file

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to update you package database, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```